# NodeJS server can't retrive post data from Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have a backend server writen in NodeJS, which use express.

I have the latest Angular as frontend, I post a data (GPG file) to the nodeJS server, and I try to get that data in NodeJS code, and print it out in the server console, but all I get is an empty object.

All I want to do is to either pass the Blob data to node server, or to pass a plain text to node server, and read it from node code.

```
const express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port);

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
//create a cors middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  //set headers to allow cross origin request.
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.post('/decrypt', (res, req) => {
  // Here I try to access the data that I passed by POST method
  console.log(res.body);
  return 'data back';
})
```

[image]

This is my Angular Code:

```
import { Injectable, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver/FileSaver';

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService {

  private API_GET_LIST_FILES = 'http://localhost:3000/files';

  private API_GET_FILE = 'http://localhost:3000/download?name=';

  private BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  getFile(key: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.API_GET_FILE + key, {
      responseType: 'blob'
    })
      .map(res => {
        return {
          filename: key.split('/').pop(),
          data: res
        };
      })
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log('start download:', res);
        // no matter what I pass here to the decrypt function, I can't get it in nodeJS server
        this.decrypt(res.filename)
        .subscribe(
          next => console.log(next)
        );
        saveAs(res.data, res.filename);

      }, error => {
        console.log('download error:', JSON.stringify(error));
      }, () => {
        console.log('Completed file download.');
      });

  }

  decrypt(res): Observable<any> {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
    })
  };
    return this.http.post(this.BASE_URL + 'decrypt', res, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

If I pass the `***res***` to the decrypt function, I will get a lot info but looks weird to me.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you passing just `res.filename` in the `decrypt` method on the front-end? While making the request to backend, you are setting headers as `application/octet-stream` but you are just passing a string as the body :/

Comment: @AnandUndavia , there is a comment above that code which says "// no matter what I pass here to the decrypt function, I can't get it in nodeJS server"

Comment: @AnandUndavia good question, but even I pass the res itself, I can't file the filename anywhere in the node server console

Comment: @ramasCoder Agreed, but the issue is with headers. Because on backend, the express only knows how to parse `application/json`, and other form headers that `bodyParser.urlencoded()` would support. The front end is saying that I'll send `application/octet-stream`, but sends a string instead. And the backend doesn't even know how to parse `application/octet-stream`

Comment: @XinruiMa, try this: set the headers as `application/json` and pass `{name:  res}` as the body

Comment: @AnandUndavia , in that case shouldn't we receive a server error ?

Comment: @AnandUndavia I get server error ``SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)``` while I pass the res.filename

Comment: Can express handle octet-stream?

Answer (score 1):

Do what Anand suggested, set headers to `application/json` (or just skip httpOptions completely as that is default) and send `{name: res}`. Request body then should be just that.

For file upload you should use Express middleware like [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) or [Multiparty](https://github.com/pillarjs/multiparty). On Angular side for example [ng2-file-upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload).

Express method callback signature is `(req, res, next)` not `(res, req)`, it is confusing when reading your code :(

And if you just `return` from callback, it will hang until http request times out (I think). You should do `res.status(200).end()` or `res.json({done: true})` or anything similar.